# how to assign network to vm using jclouds in openstack and How to list all networks in Openstack using Jclouds

Tags: openstack, jclouds, openstack-neutron

Can someone help me understanding how to assign a specific network to a newly created VM using the JClouds API in OpenStack? I'm using following code to create the real server:

```
CreateServerOptions[] serverOptions = new CreateServerOptions[0];

ServerCreated serverCreated = serverApi.create(clonedVmName, imageId, FlavourId, serverOptions);
```

Also I'm using `v1.0-quantum` APIs to fetch all the networks as follows but it's not returning any. I'm not sure what's wrong with the following code:

```
Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(
              new SLF4JLoggingModule());

      quantum = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
            .endpoint("http://10.37.53.229:5000/v2.0/")
            .credentials(identity, password)
            .modules(modules)
            .build();


      QuantumApi quanApi =  (QuantumApi)quantum.getApi();
      for(String zone : quanApi.getConfiguredZones())
      {
          System.out.println("Zone : "+ zone);
      }

      NetworkApi netApi = quanApi.getNetworkApiForZone("RegionOne");
      FluentIterable<? extends Network> nets = netApi.list();

      for(Network net : nets)
      {
          System.out.println(net.getName() +" Id : "+net.getId());
      }
```

Comment: The Neutron (previously Quantum) APIs have been updated in jclouds 1.7.0. Can you give those a try? See [how to install the OpenStack dependencies](http://jclouds.apache.org/documentation/quickstart/openstack/#install).

Answer (score 0):

I use version 1.7.3 of JClouds and I build the options in the following way, giving network ids as parameters:

```
 CreateServerOptions options = CreateServerOptions.Builder
       .networks("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111")
```

As for listing networks [here](https://gist.github.com/everett-toews/8701756) are good examples.